# How to position a table at the right margin and at the exact height of the current line?

Tags: tables, positioning

I'm trying to position the table such that the top of the table would have the same height as the text next to it, but there's always an exceedingly annoying line that I can't seem to get rid of.
[image]

Basically, I just want the table to move up a height of one line.

```
\item \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} Multiply the value of each region with its
corresponding probability,  then sum up the results. \end{minipage} \begin{minipage}
[t]{4cm} \begin{tabular}[t]{|r|l|} \hline Probability & Region \\ \hline 0.0077 & -3 \\
\hline 0.0462 & -2 \\ \hline 0.2462 & -1 \\ \hline 0.4077 & 0 \\ \hline 0.2385 & 1 \\
\hline 0.0462 & 2 \\ \hline 0.0077 & 3 \\ \hline \end{tabular} \end{minipage}
```

Comment: use array package and `\firsthline` instead of `\hline` for the top rule. Please always post complete small document not just a fragment. (also you don't need the minipage around the tabular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `adjustbox` package in the following manner:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item test
    \item \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} 
          Multiply the value of each region with its corresponding probability,  then sum up the results. 
          \end{minipage}
          \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}                % Comment if using the option below.
          %\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,raise=0.125ex} % Uncomment to get the baseline of the text and the first line of the table aligned.
          \begin{tabular}{|r|l|} 
          \hline Probability & Region \\ \hline 
          0.0077 & -3 \\ \hline 
          0.0462 & -2 \\ \hline 
          0.2462 & -1 \\ \hline 
          0.4077 & 0 \\ \hline 
          0.2385 & 1 \\ \hline 
          0.0462 & 2 \\ \hline 
          0.0077 & 3 \\ \hline 
          \end{tabular}
          \end{adjustbox}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it would be nicer if the baseline of the text and the first line of the table were aligned.  the table is just a bit lower.

Comment: @barbarabeeton See updated answer, even though I am not content about how I got the `0.125ex` to raise by. I would want to do this automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I omit the tabular's lines at the top, bottom, left and right. Then use the `[t]` option of tabular to force alignment on the first line. Finally, put the surrounding lines back with `\fbox`, which preserves the baseline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item test
\item \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        Multiply the value of each region with its corresponding
        probability,  then sum up the results.
      \end{minipage}
{\fboxsep0pt
\fbox{\begin{tabular}[t]{r|l}
    Probability & Region \\ \hline
    0.0077 & -3 \\ \hline
    0.0462 & -2 \\ \hline
    0.2462 & -1
  \end{tabular}}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```